# Why filter2D in OpenCV gives different results than imfilter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, convolution

I have an original image:

[image]

I then read it, create a PSF, and blur it in Matlab:

```
lenawords1=imread('lenawords.bmp');
%create PSF
sigma=6;
PSFgauss=fspecial('gaussian', 8*sigma+1, sigma);

%blur it
lenablur1=imfilter(lenawords1, PSFgauss, 'conv');
lenablurgray1=mat2gray(lenablur1);
PSFgauss1 = PSFgauss/max(PSFgauss(:));
```

and I saved the blurred image:

```
imwrite(lenablurgray1, 'lenablur.bmp');
imwrite(PSFgauss1, 'PSFgauss.bmp');
```

Their values in Matlab and OpenCV match.

Matlab:

```
 disp(lenablurgray1(91:93, 71:75)*256)
142.2222  147.9111  153.6000  159.2889  164.9778
153.6000  164.9778  170.6667  176.3556  176.3556
164.9778  176.3556  182.0444  187.7333  187.7333

disp(PSFgauss1(24:26, 24:26)*256)
248.9867  252.4690  248.9867
252.4690  256.0000  252.4690
248.9867  252.4690  248.9867
```

OpenCV:

```
Mat img = imread("lenablur.bmp");
cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat kernel = imread("PSFgauss.bmp");
cvtColor(kernel, kernel, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

for (int r = 90; r < 93; r++) {
    for (int c = 70; c < 75; c++) {
        cout << (int)img.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

142 147 153 159 164
153 164 ...
164 ...

cout << "PSF" << endl;
for (int r = 23; r < 26; r++) {
    for (int c = 23; c < 26; c++) {
        cout << (int)kernel.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

248 251 248
251 255 251
248 251 248
```

However, the values from `filter2D` in OpenCV and `imfilter` in Matlab do not match:

Matlab:

```
conv1=imfilter(lenablurgray1, PSFgauss1, 'conv');

disp(conv1(91:93, 71:75))
91.8094   96.1109   99.8904  103.1280  105.8210
97.3049  101.7757  105.6828  109.0073  111.7486
102.0122  106.5953  110.5755  113.9353  116.6769
```

OpenCV:

```
Mat conv1; 
filter2D(img, conv1, img.depth(), kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0,
BORDER_REFLECT);

for (int r = 90; r < 93; r++) {
    for (int c = 70; c < 75; c++) {
        cout << (int)conv1.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255
```

Why are the `filter2D` values wrong?

**EDIT2:**

```
cv::Mat kernel = imread("PSFgauss.bmp");
cvtColor(kernel, kernel, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_64F);
cv::Scalar kernelsum= cv::sum(kernel);
divide(kernel, kernelsum, kernel);

filter2D(img, conv1, img.depth(), kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_REFLECT);

for (int r = 90; r < 93; r++) {
    for (int c = 70; c < 75; c++) {
        cout << (int)conv1.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
}
```

gives

```
103 108 112 116 119
109 ..
115 ..
```

which matches the Matlab values of `conv1` when multiplied by the factor 1.133

```
disp(conv1(91:93, 71:75) * 1.133)

104.0201  108.8937  113.1758  116.8441  119.8952
110.2464  115.3118  119.7386  123.5053  126.6112
115.5798  120.7725  125.2820  129.0887  132.1950
```

However, the values differ when I divide `img` by `conv1`:

Matlab:

```
conv2 = lenablurgray1./conv1
disp(conv2(91:93, 71:75))

0.0061    0.0060    0.0060    0.0060    0.0061
0.0062    0.0063    0.0063    0.0063    0.0062
0.0063    0.0065    0.0064    0.0064    0.0063
```

OpenCV:

```
Mat conv2;
divide(img, conv1, conv2);

for (int r = 90; r < 93; r++) {
    for (int c = 70; c < 75; c++) {
        cout << (int)conv2.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 ...
1 ...
```

why is this?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
lenablur1 = imfilter(lenawords1, PSFgauss, 'conv');
```

in MATLAB, `PSFgauss` is normalized. That means that its values sum up to 1:

```
sum(PSFgauss(:)) == 1.0  % or at least it should be very close
```

Next, you scale it so its maximum value is 1, so that you can save it as a BMP file. This additionally causes rounding of the values to 256 distinct integers.

Then, in OpenCV, you read in the kernel using `imread("PSFgauss.bmp")`, and convert back to a grey-value image. This results in a kernel that has integer values in the range [0,255]. In particular, it is not normalized.

What happens then in the convolution is that you multiply each kernel element by an image pixel, and sum up all the values to produce one output value. If the kernel is normalized, this amounts to a weighted averaging. If the kernel is not normalized, the mean image intensity will not be preserved. Since the kernel here has values much larger than it originally had, the output values will be much larger than those of the input image. Because the input image is an 8-bit unsigned integer, and OpenCV uses saturated addition, the operation results in the value 255 for every pixel.

In mathematical notation, in MATLAB you do

*g* = *f* * *k*

(* is convolution, *f* is the image, *k* is the kernel). In OpenCV you do

*g'* = *f* * *Ck*

(where *C* is a constant approximately equal to `255/max(PSFgauss(:)`, which is the factor by which the kernel was multiplied during the transition from MATLAB to OpenCV).

Thus, dividing by *C* should bring the kernel back in the state it was when you used it for convolving in MATLAB. But note that the rounding effect you will not be able to remove.

The simplest way of deriving *C* in OpenCV is to divide `kernel` by its sum:

```
kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_64F);
kernel /= cv::sum(kernel);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the `EDIT` but the results are still bad

Comment: @user5739619: Try `divide(kernel, kernelsum, kernel);`

Comment: @user5739619: doesn't `/=` work with OpenCV? I made that assumption, I did see some code with `+=`.

Comment: @user5739619: also, the image is now F64, so you need to use `kernel.at<double>(r, c)` instead of `(int)kernel.at<uchar>(r, c)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, in the new `EDIT`, I am now getting a problem when I divide `conv1` by the original blurred image

Comment: I don't know what you expect to see there... But in the OpenCV version of that code you're using integer division (i.e. the result is rounded down). If I look at your values of `img` and `conv1`, I see 142/103==1, 147/108==1, etc. In some parts of your image, `conv1` will be larger than `img`, and in some parts it will be smaller. The convolution is a local (weighted) average of pixel values, the average over the neighborhood can be larger or smaller than the central pixel.

Comment: I was expecting the result to be similar to the value for `conv2` in matlab

Comment: It is, but remember that `img` in OpenCV is 255 times larger than the original image in MATLAB because of the transfer through an 8-bit unsigned integer BMP file, and that `img` in OpenCV is an 8-bit unsigned integer, and therefore the division becomes and integer division and not a floating-point division as you do in MATLAB. You need to take care of all these things. Convert your image to doubles in OpenCV, and divide by 255. Then apply the convolution, then the rest of your operations and comparisons.

Comment: You might also want to create the Gaussian kernel in OpenCV, because what you have there now has been discretized and therefore cannot be identical.